# PHP Extensions Crash Apache HTTP Server on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: apache-2.2, php

- Apache 2.2.15 (32-bit)
- PHP 5.3.2 VC6 Thread-Safe (32-bit)
- Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit)
- Intel Core 2 Duo T7200 2 GHz

Apache Service Monitor recognizes PHP, but crashes if ANY extension is enabled in PHP.ini. If I disable them all, as below, then it works.

```
;[PHP_BZ2]
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;[PHP_CURL]
;extension=php_curl.dll
;[PHP_GD2]
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;[PHP_GETTEXT]
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;[PHP_IMAP]
;extension=php_imap.dll
;[PHP_MBSTRING]
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;[PHP_MYSQL]
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;[PHP_MYSQLI]
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;[PHP_OPENSSL]
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;[PHP_PDO_MYSQL]
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;[PHP_PDO_ODBC]
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;[PHP_PDO_SQLITE]
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;[PHP_PGSQL]
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;[PHP_SOAP]
;extension=php_soap.dll
;[PHP_SOCKETS]
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;[PHP_SQLITE3]
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;[PHP_TIDY]
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;[PHP_XMLRPC]
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;[PHP_XSL]
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;[PHP_EXIF]
;extension=php_exif.dll
```

**Update:** Ran Dependency Walker on httpd per Ignacio's suggestion and it returned this:

```
IESHIMS.DLL  Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).
```

with this in the log:

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

And for the modules (using mod_alias as an example):

```
LIBAPR-1.DLL  Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).
LIBAPRUTIL-1.DLL  Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).
LIBHTTPD.DLL  Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2).
```

Log:

```
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renistalling both Apache and PHP somehow fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

A typical reason for a crash when using PHP with httpd is a library mismatch. Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on httpd as well as the extensions to look for library conflicts.

Comment: I ran it but have no idea how to interpret the results. Added them to the OP.